# Javascript Object Properties Calculated (on the fly) from Other Object Properties

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I am trying to create a javascript object that calculates various values for the properties set on it. I have compiled this simple example of what I am trying to achieve: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jrulle/jrbvy12k/2/)**

```
var obj = {};
obj.a = 2;
obj.b = 5;
obj.avg = "(obj.a + obj.b)/2"; 
obj.rounded = "Math.floor(eval(obj.avg))";

console.log("rounded avg: " + eval(obj.rounded));
//simulate changing properties
obj.a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
obj.b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
console.log("rounded avg: " + eval(obj.rounded));
```

The above code currently achieves what I want (using standard set values like 'a' and 'b' to calculate 'avg' then using 'avg' in a second calculation 'rounded').

Is there a better way to achieve this (ideally without the `eval()` calls whenever a calculated property is referenced in another property).

What I would like is for the calculated properties to act like functions (calculate their value whenever they are referenced) rather than calculating their value initially and not changing - I would like to avoid having to use `()` to call the functions (so that I can reference both the plain values and the calculated values the same way - just by their property name).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Instead of using `eval`, use functions as follows:

```js
var obj = {};
obj.a = 2;
obj.b = 5;
obj.avg = function() { return (this.a + this.b) / 2; };
obj.rounded = function() { return Math.floor(this.avg()); };

console.log("rounded avg: " + obj.rounded());
obj.a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
obj.b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
console.log("rounded avg: " + obj.rounded());
```

If you don't have to support old browsers, to avoid having to use parentheses when calling the functions, you could use [getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) as follows:

```js
var obj = {
  a: 2,
  b: 5,
  get avg() { return (this.a + this.b) / 2; },
  get rounded() { return Math.floor(this.avg) }
}

console.log("rounded avg: " + obj.rounded);
obj.a = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
obj.b = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
console.log("rounded avg: " + obj.rounded);
```

Comment: Sure, but the OP said "I would like to avoid having to use () to call the functions".

Comment: @torazaburo I was "getting" to that :-)

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Ha, now I *`get`* it — “getting”…

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen thank you for the very complete answer. I would really like to use the 'getter' syntax but unfortunately I need to support IE8 so it looks like I am stuck with the functions. Here is my updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jrbvy12k/4/) showing the solution I worked together from your answer (basically I am using '_val' to name plain values and I set up accessor functions so that I can reference properties in calculated values using a common, function style syntax)

Answer (score 7):

Use [Getters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get) if you don’t need to support Internet Explorer 8 or less:

```
var obj = {
  a:2,
  b:5,
  get avg(){
    return (this.a + this.b)/2;
  }, 
  get rounded(){
    return Math.floor(this.avg);
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
obj.a; // returns 2
obj.b; // returns 5
obj.avg; // returns 3.5
obj.rounded; // returns 3
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I really wish I could use the getter syntax but I need to support IE8.

Answer (score 1):

It appears you are after what is called a *computed property*. This is a variable that is computed when it is asked for. In Javascript, you can use the [Object Getter/Setter Syntax](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/)

Comment: First time I read this question I thought about computed property names… `obj=({[propname]:6})`.

Comment: @Xufox Why the parens around the object?

Comment: @torazaburo Sometimes I get “_SyntaxError: missing ; before statement_” when writing objects into the console without an assignment… so just to be safe…

Comment: In isolation, yes, you need the parens, because otherwise the `{` is interpreted as the beginning of a block. On the right side of an assignment, where a block could not come, not needed. Whatever.